# MySql, 3 tables, need all columns using ID from main table

Tags: php, mysql

I can only assume this has been asked, I have been looking here for over an hour and may have looked right at it and not known it was my answer. Please forgive me if this is the case, possibly point me to the correct answer maybe?

I have a main table of characters, main ID in this table. The other two tables are referenced by the char_id. I am wanting to pull all columns from all three tables matching the characters table ID number.

```
Characters
id, col1, col2, col3

equip_profiles
id, char_id, col1, col2, col3

inventory
id, char_id, col1, col2, col3
```

Need a return of

```
characters.id, characters.col1, characters.col2, characters.col3, equip_profiles.col1, equip_profiles.col2, equip_profiles.col3, inventory.col1,
inventory.col2, inventory.col3,
```

I of course have several more columns in all tables and just trying to get everything from all three tables using characters.id is the root ID and char_id as the pointer back to characters.

PLEASE HELP!

```
SELECT characters.*, equip_profiles.*, inventory.* 
FROM characters 
JOIN equip_profiles ON characters.id = equip_profiles.char_id 
JOIN inventory ON characters.id = inventory.char_id
```

Comment: what's your problem .. you have error? show error message... wrong result? update your question add  a proper data sample, the expected  result and your actual result

Comment: is threre any error that you get ?

Comment: Do you say that you have many tables with field name as `char_id` and you want to find and to join those tables? Or it is just two tables  with char_id field?

Comment: No error, just missing results. I wish I had a way to create an example to show, or better explain. The query I am using does return results.

Comment: Code Name Jack, there is the main table, characters. This characters table references 2 other tables (soon to be 3). The other tables all have an id named "char_id", to point back to the character in the main table. All columns from the other two tables are needed, I am wanting a return with the character ID and all the rows from the other two tables. (Soon will have the third, so, I am guessing this would be three joins).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table name is `Characters` but in the query you're using it as `characters`. That could be the problem, also I recommend the usage of alias for tables as:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.* 
FROM characters a  
FULL OUTER JOIN equip_profiles b ON a.id = b.char_id 
FULL OUTER JOIN inventory c ON a.id = c.char_id
```

Edit: 
The FULL OUTER JOIN keyword return all records when there is a match in either left (table1) or right (table2) table records on matching condition.

Comment: Hello Haseeb, thank you for your reply. The "Characters"/"characters" was a simple mistype when entering the post here. The actual query is posted above after the PLEASE HELP. This query does report back without errors, but does not produce the expected results. It looks as though its only getting the data from the third table and giving me only the results from what it finds matching in the first and second tables. I need all the columns from all tables even if null.

Answer (score 0):

Here all three tables contain same column name id , you have to specify other two tables id with other name like

> equip_profiles.id as eqid
>
> inventory.id as invid

or you may specify your select query as you stated what you want

the query might be like

```
SELECT characters.*, equip_profiles.id as eqid,equip_profiles.col1, inventory.id as invid,inventory.col1
FROM characters 
JOIN equip_profiles ON characters.id = equip_profiles.char_id 
JOIN inventory ON characters.id = inventory.char_id,
```

Comment: I am sure I dont understand this really. I did copy this and it returns an error. The characters table is primary and everything is needed from this table. the second and third both contain a col named char_id. I would like the query to select all records from the second and third table where their corresponding ID column named "char_id" is the same as the characters ID column.